# My Coroutine stops after 'yield return new WaitForSeconds(.01f)'

Tags: c#, coroutine

I'm trying to make my coroutine load a scene, then almost immediately teleport the player to a specific location in the scene (Which is why I have .01f in the time). However, after

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(.01f);
```

The code after it doesn't run. "After Coroutine" doesn't appear in my log and the teleporting doesn't run.

```
    private IEnumerator Exiting()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Opening Stage");
        Debug.Log("Scene loaded, lastPos: " + myLocation.getLastPos());
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.01f);

        Debug.Log("After Coroutine");
        myLocation.ReturnToLastPos();

    }
```

Removing the LoadScene line makes it all work, teleporting and all. But loading the scene is needed and I've been trying to figure it out. I'm still relatively new to C# so if I don't understand your suggestions or comments, that's why. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to wait at all? Also, how are you calling the `Exiting` method?

Comment: I need to wait because in a normal method, it teleports THEN loads the scene, even though my code says to load the scene then teleport. It results with the scene loading with the player in a default position. I'm calling the Exiting method in my update method when the conditions are met ```StartCorouting(Exiting())```

Comment: `yield`, well, _yields_ execution.  From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield): "When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called." Is whatever method that iterates over `Exiting()` stopping its iteration after the first element is returned?